# Python what is recursion doing here after it ends?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new to python programming. I wrote a small script for recursion that helps me understand what is going on within the recursion loop. But after the recursion ends, I don't understand the last part of my script and what it is doing. Here's my script.

```
def test(n, m, p, k):
    print(n, m, p, k, 'This is the value coming in.')
    if n > 0:
        print(n, m, p, k, 'This is before recursion.')
        test(n-1, p, k, m)
        print(n, m, p, k, 'This is when n = 1.' )
```

This is the result when I run >>> test(5, 10, 20, 30)

```
5 10 20 30 This is the value coming in.
5 10 20 30 This is before recursion.
4 20 30 10 This is the value coming in.
4 20 30 10 This is before recursion.
3 30 10 20 This is the value coming in.
3 30 10 20 This is before recursion.
2 10 20 30 This is the value coming in.
2 10 20 30 This is before recursion.
1 20 30 10 This is the value coming in.
1 20 30 10 This is before recursion.
0 30 10 20 This is the value coming in.
1 20 30 10 This is when n = 1.
2 10 20 30 This is when n = 1.
3 30 10 20 This is when n = 1.
4 20 30 10 This is when n = 1.
5 10 20 30 This is when n = 1.
```

Why is the last 5 print function is going up from n=1 to n=5?

Comment: oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's when all the calls are unwrapping. n is descending, so when it unwraps it will be in reverse order (first call is last to resolve). You can see this by looking at the parameters in detail on the last few lines.